# Generate random v shaped int array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, random, numbers

I have to generate v shaped, ascending and descending random int array for sorting tests. I have no idea how to achive that. Here is my implementation for 100k array of random ints.

```
        Random rnd = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());            
        int[] array = new int[100000];

        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            array[i] = rnd.Next(100000);
        }
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: "*generate v shaped, ascending and descending random int array"* - can you describe what is it? Perhaps with an example of data set.

Answer (score 3):

Generate two lists of 50k - sort the first ascending, sort the second descending ([Better way to sort array in descending order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430016/better-way-to-sort-array-in-descending-order)) & join the two arrays ([How do I concatenate two arrays in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547252/how-do-i-concatenate-two-arrays-in-c))

Answer (score 1):

> I have to generate v shaped, ascending and descending random int array
>   for sorting tests

I would reconsider the scenario. This kind of test should not be based on random values. From a [similiar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32901743/create-object-hierarchy-for-test) question:

> Randomly live-generated data in tests is not a good idea. there's no
>   way you can guarantee the test conditions will be the same every time,
>   and no guarantee that you cover every possible scenario.

Instead you can simply make sure that a specific scenario is covered.

```
        int numberOfItems = 100000;
        int[] array = new int[numberOfItems];
        int count = 0;

        for (int i = numberOfItems / 2; i > 0; i--)
        {
            array[count++] = i;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems / 2; i++)
        {
            array[count++] = i;
        }
```